# jquery to restrict date ranges based on another selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using a `jquery datepicker` which is used to initialize both start date and end date. I am restricting all dates before the present date for start date. for my end date I want it to restrict all dates which are less than or equal to the start date. the code is as given below.
`beforeShowDay` is a function call which would disable all days before today for both start date and end date.

```
$( ".datePicker" ).datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: NotBeforeToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) 
    {        
      if( $(this).hasClass('StartDate') ){
          var StartDate= $(this).val();
          ActDate = new Date(StartDate);
      }else if( $(this).hasClass('EndDate') ){
          var EndDate= $(this).val();
          ExpDate = new Date(EndDate);
      }  
    }
 });
```

Comment: when i select the date from end date it should disable all dates before the selected date of the start date

Comment: can you pls share jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one option in [Jquery DatePicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to set [minDate.](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) You set min date by setting this option value.This will disable all date before minDate set by minDate option.

Your onSelect function include below code to set start date for EndDate :

```
$( ".datePicker" ).datepicker({          
     minDate : new Date(),  //Set current date to minimum date to select
     onSelect: function(selectedDate) 
      {        
          if( $(this).hasClass('StartDate') ){
             var StartDate= $(this).val();
             $( "EndDatePickerselector" ).datepicker('option', 'minDate', StartDate);
          } 
       }  
 });
```

If you want restrict date selector to some maximum date limit you can use [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option to set maximum date selection for date selector.

[**JsFiddel Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/337/)

May this will help you.